# How to change the cybersource Payment gateway "Silent order Post" to "Secure Acceptance Silent Order POST" in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to change the cybersource Payment gateway  "Silent order Post" to "Secure Acceptance Silent Order POST" in vb.net.
I have passed the Secret key, Profile id and Access key But I got "You are not authorized to view this page. The transaction has not been processed." error.
How to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kailash

Comment: Show us some code examples

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know what you encountered without more information, but I encountered the same thing.

https://support.cybersource.com/cybskb/index?page=content&id=CS289

Basically, I had to make sure that I had the correct Secret Key, Access Key, and Profile Id.  My profile ID was a guid unlike many in the tutorials found online.

The other thing I had to do was to make sure I restarted/recompiled things so that the keys were actually being used.